# Where IN Clause in PHP & output of while loop outside of while

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, trim

My Php code is

```
<?php
include('session.php');
include('db.php');

$session=$_SESSION['agent'];

$home1 = "SELECT fullname FROM users WHERE role='$session'";
$result1=mysql_query($home1) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

echo $gallery = "'".$row1[0]."',"; // output is 'sam','teja','multiplevaluessoon',


$home = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE chat.from IN ('$gallery')";
}
$result=mysql_query($home) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $msg         =$row["message"];
    echo $randomUserId=$row["from"];
   echo $msg . "<br/>";
   }
 ?>
```

here $gallery contains ',' comma at the end, so i am getting a error in where clause, when i am trying to trim the output of $gallery

```
 'sam','teja','multiplevaluessoon',
```

last charcter inside loop i am getting

```
 'sam''teja''multiplevaluessoon'
```

which is trimming all the commas due to while loop, i need last comma to be trimmed so that i can execute it in where clause

please suggest me any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [`rtrim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php).

```
$yourfinaltext = rtrim($yourcommadelimitedstring, ',');
```

Change your `while` like this.

```
while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

      $gallery .= "'".$row1[0]."',";
      $home = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE chat.from IN ('$gallery')";
}
echo rtrim($gallery,',');
```

Comment: thats what i explained there, when i trim that it is removing all the commas as it is inside while loop

Comment: You need to do this outside of the `while` loop .. That's why i put the variable name as `$yourfinaltext`

Comment: but outside the loop i will not get the output same as inside the loop, outside the loop it will only print the last value of the column

Answer (score 1):

```
$rest = substr("abcdef", 0, -1);  // returns "abcde"
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma as this...

```
$gallery=substr_replace($gallery ,'',0,1);
```